# Laravel 5 where clause from another table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a simple code and what I want to do is to access a field from another table and put it in my where clause. This is my code:

**ReportController.php**

```
$reservations = Reservation::with('charge', 'room', 'client')
-> whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])
-> where('room.type', \Request::input('type')) //what should this be
-> orderBy('created_at')
-> get();
```

**Room.php**

```
class Room extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'rooms';

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'roomNumber', 'type', 'price', 'description'];

    public function reservations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Reservation', 'id', 'room_number');
    }
}
```

**Reservation.php**

```
class Reservation extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = 'reservations';

    protected $fillable = ['roomNumber', 'clientId', 'reservation_from', 'reservation_to'];

    public function room() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Room');
    }

}
```

**Schema:**
[image]

As you can see in the `ReportController.php`, there is a comment saying "what should this be", that's the part that I want to fix. What I wanted to do is access the `type` field in the rooms table in my eloquent query.

The query that I want to do is like this:

```
select * from `reservations` where `reservation_from` between '2015-10-29' and '2015-10-29' and `rooms.type` = "test"
```

Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by access, from where?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `whereHas` method.

```
$reservations = Reservation::with('charge', 'room', 'client')
    ->whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])
    ->whereHas('room', function($query) {
        $query->where('type', '=', \Request::input('type'));
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at')
    ->get();
```

Link to docs: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

Edit:

Editing this to clarify some things in the comments.

To create convenient, reusable query constraints to make your code cleaner, you can use query constraints: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

Also, because queries can be chained, you can do something like this:

```
// Create query with common constraints
$query = Reservation::with('charge', 'room', 'client')
    ->whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to]);

// Ternary operator to decide whether or not to add whereHas constraint
$query = (\Request::input('type') == "all") ? $query : $query->whereHas('room', function($query) {
    $query->where('type', '=', \Request::input('type'));
});

// Finally, fetch the results sorted by 'latest', which is a convenient way of doing "orderBy('created')"
$reservations = $query->latest()->get();
```

Comment: @FewFlyBy this is how you do it.

Comment: Thank you very much.. can I chat with you for a sec?

Comment: Look at query scopes to create convenient, reusable query constraints. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes

Also, because they are chainable by nature, you can probably do something like this (looks very ugly in comments): `$query = Reservation::with('charge', 'room', 'client')->whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to]);
$query = (\Request::input('type') == "all") ? $query : $query->whereHas('room', function($query) {
                        $query->where('type', '=', \Request::input('type'));
                    });
$reservations = $query->latest()->get();`

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking to do this. Updated per your question update. The `with` method takes a string or an array.

```
$reservations = Reservation::with(['charge', 'client', 'room' =>   
    function($query){
        $query->where('type', \Request::input('type'));
    }])
->whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])
->orderBy('created_at')
->get();
```

Comment: @FewFlyBy let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @FewFlyBy forgot the `;`